Which partition should be bootable, and why?
Using Debian 12.5 Bookworm, 64bit
I wanted to teach myself how to partition my disks for my needs, so I did this:
——————————————————————————————| [!!] Partition Disks |——————————————————————————————
This is an overview of your currently configured partitions and mount points.
Select a partition to modify its settings (file system, mount point, etc.),
a free space to create partitions, or a device to initialize its partition table.

    Guided Partitioning
    Configure software RAID
    Configure the Logical Volume Manager
    Configure encrypted volumes
    Configure iSCSI volumes
    
    LVM VG deblvm-vg-home, LV deblvm-lv-home - 14.7 GB Linux device-mapper (linear)
        #1  14.7 GB f   ext4    /home
    LVM VG deblvm-vg-usr, LV deblvm-lv-usr - 14.9 GB Linux device-mapper (linear)
        #1  14.9 GB f   ext4    /usr
    LVM VG deblvm-vg-var, LV deblvm-lv-var - 14.9 GB Linux device-mapper (linear)
        1#  14.9 GB f   ext4    /var
    Virtual disk 1 (vda) - 107.4 GB Virtio Block Device
        1#  primary 1.1 GB  B   F   ext2    /boot
        2#  primary 53.2 GB     F   ext4    /
        5#  logical 8.6 GB      F   swap
        6#  logical 14.7 GB     K   lvm
        7#  logical 14.9 GB     K   lvm
        8#  logical 14.9 GB     K   lvm

In some places I saw that I need to make at least one partition bootable to make the system work. that's what I've learned:

If you use BIOS, then you need to flag /boot as bootable.
If you use UEFI, then you need to flag / as bootable, or /boot/efi.
You must install grub to the bootable partition (e.g. vda1 and not just vda)

So my questions are:
Is this correct? Am I doing things wrong? Where can I learn about which partition should be bootable and which shouldn't, and why?
Thank you

It is not so much about partitions but the BIOS/(UEFI) capabilities of your machine. Old machines won't have UEFI so you could not boot using OS EFI partitions, no matter if you created or not. Other machines coud boot both legacy and EFI and you can configure the BIOS to do one or the other. So to manage what type of booting you will set up first you must know if the target machine is capable of. See Debians docs UEFI vs BIOS boot.

Besides the learning process, modern Linux distros generally handle this (sort of) automatically in the installation process, if you booted your installation media via UEFI then the installer creates an EFI partition for example.

That depends entirely on how you intend to boot your system.
Most PC BIOSes nowadays default to booting in EFI/UEFI, which bypasses the whole 'bootable partition' entirely and instead uses a dedicated EFI partition that stores the boot loaders for each OS or other function supporting EFI on the system.
If your system is set to use it (again, probably, because it's the default, but you could open up the BIOS screen to check for sure) then during the install, grub will install grub-efi to hook into the UEFI partition and none of your actual partitions will need to be bootable.
If you're still using legacy BIOS boot (there is really no good reason to unless you're dealing with a legacy setup that predates UEFI and can't be arsed to make the changeover) then you'll need to make the partition you install grub to bootable.
But seriously, if you can, use UEFI. It makes a lot of things a hell of a lot easier.

Incidentally I have a server (from 2009) and was stuck trying to install Debian 12.5 in EFI mode, the installer would just freeze after selecting any of the 'Install' options of GRUB. Tried different USBs, tweaked the BIOS and different ISOs, messed with GRUB command line. I could only get to boot in legacy mode.  Ubuntu (22.04) booted just fine with EFI.
